# Include the user history visibility settings in a feature

Tags: users, features

I have two view modes for the user profiles, the default one and a custom view mode called "Header". In the default view mode I have chosen to show the user history information ("Member for...") but in the Header view mode it shouldn't be shown.

I have included the user account settings in a feature in order to be able to export them. Everything else is fine but I don't find how to include the history visibility settings in it. When I reinstall the site with my feature, the "Member for..." information is shown in both of the view modes. I can manually hide it in the configuration page, but I must find how to export it into the code.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've added a custom visibility option to User accounts. You'll need to figure out a way to export it to code. if they are just Fields then they should show up under export options for Fields when building a feature.

If on the other hand you've created a custom tab of sorts on the User Accounts page and have a bit of code managing some settings there -- you need to inform Drupal of those pieces of custom data.

[Features Extras](https://drupal.org/project/features_extra) supports exporting visibility settings for blocks, and blocks in general.

> To export a block, install FE Block, edit your block, give it a
>   "machine name," export it with Features. You can export block settings
>   (region settings, visibility settings, ...) of any block, and the
>   content of blocks created with the Block module from Drupal core.

I recommend looking at that module and seeing how they export these settings. If I had to guess I'd say they use the Ctools Export API. [There is a drupal handbook page on how to get started exporting configuration for your module](https://drupal.org/node/928026).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem isn't actually the custom fields etc. – those are included in the feature and exported, but I cannot find the core's 'member_for' visibility when I try to recreate my feature. It's not a field instance, a field base, nor a variable. I cannot see anything that would allow me to include it into the feature...

Comment: right, so did you look at features extra to see how they achieve the same thing with block visibility settings ... ?

Comment: Thank you! That's it, I'm sorry I didn't understand that at the first lecture of your message. In the Features Extra module there is FE Profile module that allows to add a variable for that setting.